# How to check the process limit on the license of mathematica?

Tags: licensing

My current calculation need to launch multiple mma kernels in our institute's cluster. However, if I launch too much tasks, there will be an error massage as following

"The $-process limit on the license you are trying to run has been reached. Contact Wolfram Research or an authorized Wolfram product distributor for information on upgrading your license configuration."

The $n is the process limit of my account.

Of cause, I can know this $n if I see this error massage. Is there any function or command in mma that can tell me this limit?

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MonitoringMathLM.html

Comment: On Windows try: "Help/ About Wolfram Mathematica" then click "System Information" in the tabbed list choose "Front End"., There you find: "Max License Processes"