# Parallel computing environment

Tags: parallelization

In the following environment

```
SystemOptions{ParallelOptions -> 
>     {AbortPause -> 2., BusyWait -> 0.01, MathLinkTimeout -> 15., 
>      MKLThreadNumber -> 32, ParallelThreadNumber -> 32, 
>      RecoveryMode -> Retry, RelaunchFailedKernels -> True, 
>      VectorParallelLengthThresholds -> {8192, 8192, 8192, 8192, 8192}, 
>      VectorVendorLengthThresholds -> {128, 32, 32}}}

ProcessorCount=32

ProcessorType=x86-64

SystemInformation{KernelCount -> 0, RunningKernels -> {}, Debugging -> False, 
>    AutomaticLaunching -> Automatic, FailedKernelRelaunching -> True, 
>    EvaluationFailureRecovery -> Retry, ProcessorCount -> 32, 
>    KernelConfiguration -> {<<16 local kernels>>}, 
>    AvailableConnectionMethods -> 
>     {SubKernels`LocalKernels`, LightweightGridClient`, ClusterIntegration`, 
>      SubKernels`RemoteKernels`, SubKernels`ClusterKernels`}, 
>    LoadedConnectionMethods -> {SubKernels`LocalKernels`}, 
>    DistributedDefinitions -> {}, ParallelPackages -> Missing[NotActive], 
>    SharedVariables -> {}, SharedFunctions -> {}, 
>    ParallelToolsVersion -> 9.0}
```

Mathematica starts exactly 16 kernels (as is stated in KernelConfiguration) How can I achieve to start/configure 32 kernels, which this machine should be capable to do? Is it a license issue?

Comment: Can you check how many kernels you can start with your license? See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/256108/27951

Comment: @MarcoB Ahh, thanks...   It's actually simply: SystemInformation["Kernel", "MaxLicenseProcesses"]